# JSON VBA with URL

Tags: json, vba

Первый раз на этом ресурсе. Не разработчик, но заинтересовался VBA. Прошу помощи. Хочу спарсить JSON из URL, но получаю ошибку `Run-time Error 13" Type Mismatch`. Понимаю что не тот тип переменной или иного, но разобраться сам уже не могу. Ниже json и сам VBA. Спасибо

```
{
    "barcode": "",
    "devCode": "1",
    "height": 0,
    "itemType": 0,
    "length": 0,
    "weight": 0,
    "width": 0
}
```

```
    Public Sub exceljson() 
    Dim http As Object, JSON As Object, i As Integer
    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    http.Open "GET", "http://******", False
    http.Send
    Set JSON = ParseJson(http.responseText)
    i = 2
    For Each Item In JSON
    Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value = Item("barcode") ' Run-time Error 13" Type Mismatch '
    Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Value = Item("devCode")
    Sheets(1).Cells(i, 3).Value = Item("height")
    Sheets(1).Cells(i, 4).Value = Item("itemType")
    Sheets(1).Cells(i, 5).Value = Item("lenght")
    Sheets(1).Cells(i, 6).Value = Item("weight")
    Sheets(1).Cells(i, 7).Value = Item("width")
    i = i + 1
    Next
    MsgBox ("complete")
    End Sub
```

Спустя некоторое время удалось почти сделать

```
Dim Movie As Object
Dim scriptControl As Object

Set scriptControl = CreateObject("MSScriptControl.ScriptControl")
scriptControl.Language = "JScript"

With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", "http://infoscan-ccbb.capdel.ru:8080/data", False
    .send
    Set Movie = scriptControl.Eval("(" + .responseText + ")")
    .abort
    With Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1, 1).Value = Movie.barcode
        .Cells(1, 2).Value = Movie.Width

    End With
End With
```

Теперь же если беру .Cells(1,1),то добавляется значение barcode,если вторую строку,то пишет object doesn't support this property or method error 438

Comment: *но получаю ошибку* В какой именно строке - видимо, секрет... хотя кажется мне, что кто-то забыл определить переменную-итератор `Item` для ForEach (да ещё использовал в качестве её имени слово, совпадающее с именем свойства некоторых объектов).

Comment: Дебаг указывает на   Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value = Item("barcode").

Comment: Откуда взята функция `ParseJson`? Какой тип значения она возвращает в переменную `JSON`, является ли этот тип коллекцией? Какой тип элемента такой коллекции, передаваемый в переменную `Item`, является ли он коллекцией, допускающей выбор элемента по строковому ключу?

Comment: Из библиотеки VBA-JSON Jsonconverter.bas. К сожалению ничего не скажу за остальные  вопросы. Переименовал в foreach переменную item и определил, как Object,дебаг ругается на foreach    ПС:тоже с Зеленограда =)

Comment: *Из библиотеки VBA-JSON Jsonconverter.bas.* Добавьте эту информацию в текст вопроса, включая ссылку на место, где публикуется этот модуль. *ничего не скажу за остальные вопросы* Поработайте, выясните, скажите (тоже добавить в текст вопроса). *определил, как Object* Подключите все необходимые реф. библиотеки и перейдите на раннее связывание, хотя бы на время разработки. *Переименовал в foreach переменную item и определил, как Object* Тоже добавить в текст вопроса - включая корректированный код.

Comment: Удалось почти сделать...